# Parse custom value from NSError

Tags: ios, objective-c, parsing, nserror

When API request fails, I need to know number of failed attempts. Backend has added a property ‘attempts’ to error object. How can I find this value, since NSError is not KV pairing compliant and I don’t see it when I log the error object to console. [image]

Comment: What does your code look like where you receive this error?

Comment: I’m using nsurlsession for requests which provides a callback with NSData, NSURLResponse, and NSError. So when request fails backend apparently adds ‘attempts’ to error object. How can retrieve this value from NSError or maybe from NSURLResponse?

Comment: When you say backend, do you mean the web service?  If so, the data won't be in the NSErrror. It will be either in the URL response as a header value or in the data itself if it is returned in the body.

Comment: @Paulw11, ok, it’s in the data. So in the case where this specific request fails and I need ‘attempts’ error is nil, and data has an object containing error info. I’ll have to make changes to networking layer for this exception.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using NSURLSession for urlrequest , then you will have delegate methods for NSURLSession responses , they are:

->didReceiveResponse = here you receive the response that urlrequest has completed and response received status

->didReceiveData = here you get the SUCCESS response date for your request

->didCompleteWithError = here you get the FAILURE response (i.e) ERROR callback ,this is called every time when request fails , which gives you error data